Filling hole to remove text in especific position?
I'd searching for a way to remove a text (watermark) for image that are always the same text and in same position (diagonal).
I´ve found some similar questions and in some suggests to fill holes in the text position, but initially I'm stuck in how to create a how in the text position.
Maybe someone could help. Regards

Update
This is the code I have so far, following this technique but the output is far from my desired one.
magick -size 530x398 xc:black -stroke white -strokewidth 45 -draw 'stroke-linecap round line 105,321 465,60' -threshold 10%  input_mask.jpg

magick input.jpg \( input_mask.jpg -negate \) -compose CopyOpacity -composite input_hole.png

magick input_hole.png -blur 0x1 -alpha off input_fill.png

magick input_hole.png input_fill.png -compose Dst_Over  -composite  input_text_removed.png

Output so far.


What have you tried - where is your code attempt?  StackOverflow is not a code writing service.  Please read the information guides in the help center (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example - And Show Code As Text, Not An Image" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

White text on a white background has little contrast with which to work!

@fmw42 please see my update. I've added my code so far and output

@Rasec Malkic Take your mask and use one of the methods that I provided in my answer to create the output.  Show your mask image and those outputs that you get. Perhaps your manual method of getting the mask will be better than the approach that I made.

Here is how to create your hole (mask) in Imagemagick. But it won't do a good job, since your background is rather flat white. It needs some texture to help. Nevertheless, hear how to create and apply the mask.
To create mask:
Line1: convert input to HSV and separate channels
Line2: convert the Value channel to fill the black vertical line with white
Line3: invert (negate) and threshold at zero
Line4: apply open morphology to get rid of the white specks around the letter
Line5: dilate to fill in the letters to make the mask

convert img.png -colorspace HSV -separate x.png
convert x-2.png -fuzz 50% -fill white -opaque black x-2b.png
convert x-2b.png -negate -threshold 0 x-2c.png
convert x-2c.png -morphology open diamond:2 x-2d.png
convert x-2d.png -morphology dilate disk:6 x-2e.png


then to make the output:
blur the input and composite the blurred image with the input using the mask

convert img.png \( +clone -blur 0x5 \) \( x-2e.png \) -compose over -composite x-2f.png


or starting with x-2e.png using the method in the link the OP provide:
Line1: negate the mask and put it into the alpha channel of the input
Line2: blur that image and turn the alpha channel off
Line4: composite the the result of Line2 under the result of Line1 to form the output 

convert img.png \( x-2e.png -negate \) -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite x-2g.png
convert x-2g.png -blur 0x4 -alpha off x-2h.png
convert x-2g.png x-2h.png -compose dst_over -composite x-2i.png

Input:

Value channel:

Inverted and thresholded:

Morphology open to remove specks:

Morphology dilate to create mask:

First Result:

Negated mask placed into alpha channel of input:

Blurred

Second Result:

Take your pick which one you like best.  Neither seem that great to me.

Thanks for your help and explanation. I have another image that has black background in some part, maybe in that one works better. I see the better result could be the "first result". It shows thta something was there but doesn´t delete too much from the part of image that I want to preserve. Do you know a better technique or if this task actually could be done without manual intervention (.i.e with photoshop or something)?

Inpainting for example with OpenCV or Skimage might work better if the letters were smaller.  They're other inpainting methods that work on patches that would work better for larger letters, but I do not know of any free software that includes that.

Search Google for "patch inpainting microsoft" or see https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/tr-2003-84.pdf
